# Mac OS X 10.6 includes Java 6?

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, java

The default install of Mac OS X 10.6 includes Java 6, or is it still Java 5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On my Mac mini under OS X 10.6.5, a `java -version` gives me Java 1.6.0_22.

It's an out of box + upgrade from 10.6.4 to 10.6.5 and installation of last Xcode 3.

Comment: Did you perform optional updates, or is it default install?

Comment: Edited post with info.

Answer (score 3):

Snow Leopard comes with Java 6, Leopard is J2SE 5. Just see any Java update support article for OS X 10.6 and there will be mention of Java SE 6 [see here.](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4297)

Answer (score 2):

According to [some](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2140099) [sources](http://www.nofluffjuststuff.com/blog/ken_sipe/2009/09/fixing_java_on_mac_snow_leopard), Snow Leopard comes with Java 6. Java 5 is not even installed.

Answer (score 1):

Snow Leopard comes with 64 bit Java 6.